# get query params from request url soapui using groovy

Tags: rest, groovy, soapui

I only used SOAP UI to just test the WSDL/URL but not in this extent. I need to get the request url query parameters from SOAP UI and use them to test some stuff using groovy script.

Lets say i have a GetCustomers request url as follows

```
`http://myendpoint.com/customers?Id=111&ModeName=abc&DeltaId=023423`
```

i need the following from URL
`Id=111`
`ModeName=abc`
`DeltaId=023423`

I created a groovy script in SOAP UI which in the following hierarchy
  TestSuit->TestCase-> TestStep->GroovyScript

In the groovy script i tried

`def id = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("Id")`

but when i print `id` i am getting it as null. I am not sure of any other configurations i need to do in order to access those query params.
Is there a way I can get those query params and access those directly in my groovy script?

Comment: Before you get too far into Groovy, you might want to read the documentation: https://www.soapui.org/rest-testing/understanding-rest-parameters.html

Answer (score 3):

Supposing that your *testStep* request is called `GetCustomers` you can use the follow *Groovy* code to get the *testStep* and then the property with the endpoint value as `String`:

```
def ts = context.testCase.getTestStepByName('GetCustomers')
def endpoint =ts.getPropertyValue('Endpoint')
log.info endpoint // prints http://myendpoint.com/customers?Id=111&ModeName=abc&DeltaId=023423
```

Then you can parse the endpoint using the [`java.net.URL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) class and use [`getQuery()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getQuery()) method to extract the query parameters. Then split by `&` to get each query name value pair and finally split again each pair with `=`and put the result in a `Map`. Altogether your code could be something like:

```
import java.net.*

def ts = context.testCase.getTestStepByName('GetCustomers')
def endpoint =ts.getPropertyValue('Endpoint')
// parse the endpoint as url
def url = new URL(endpoint)
// get all query params as list
def queryParams = url.query?.split('&') // safe operator for urls without query params
// transform the params list to a Map spliting 
// each query param
def mapParams = queryParams.collectEntries { param -> param.split('=').collect { URLDecoder.decode(it) }}
// assert the expected values
assert mapParams['Id'] == '111'
assert mapParams['ModeName']== 'abc'
assert mapParams['DeltaId']=='023423'
```

There is another option without using `URL` class; which simply consists on splitting the `URL` using `?`  to get the query parameters (as `URL.getQuery()` does):

```
def ts = context.testCase.getTestStepByName('GetCustomers')
def endpoint =ts.getPropertyValue('Endpoint')

// ? it's a special regex... so escape it
def queryParams = endpoint.split('\\?')[1].split('&')
// transform the params list to a Map spliting 
// each query param
def mapParams = queryParams.collectEntries { param -> param.split('=').collect { it }}
// assert the expected values
assert mapParams['Id'] == '111'
assert mapParams['ModeName']== 'abc'
assert mapParams['DeltaId']=='023423'
```

Comment: The above treated all values as strings. To convert to `int` try ternary operator something like `val.isInteger() ? val.toInteger() : val`