# How to parse a URL to fetch it's parameters in groovy?

Tags: groovy, soapui, urlparse

I am new to groovy scripting and looking on to parse the URL and print it's parameter.

This url is : [https://www.google.com/?aaa=111&bbb=222&ccc=33&**dd**=1484088989_b23f248ac6e5d9a9b47475526bb92ee1](https://www.google.com/?aaa=111&bbb=222&ccc=33&__dd__=1484088989_b23f248ac6e5d9a9b47475526bb92ee1)

How can i fetch *dd* parameter from the URL?

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Have you tried any? How do you get the url? Is it fixed? or dynamic? do you get it as string? May be adding more details on your case would help. You may also look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get query params from request url soapui using groovy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535861/get-query-params-from-request-url-soapui-using-groovy)

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a groovy script.

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context );
def testCase = context.testCase;
def testStep = testCase.getTestStepByName("NAME_TESTStepRequest");  
def endpoint =testStep.getPropertyValue('Endpoint');
log.info endpoint;
def url = new URL(endpoint)
//def url = new URL("https://www.google.com/?aaa=111&bbb=222&ccc=33&dd=1484088989_b23f248ac6e5d9a9b47475526bb92ee1")

// get all query params as list
def queryParams = url.query?.split('&') // safe operator for urls without query params
// transform the params list to a Map spliting 
// each query param
def mapParams = queryParams.collectEntries { param -> param.split('=').collect { URLDecoder.decode(it) }}
// assert the expected values
log.info mapParams['aaa']
//assert mapParams['aaa'] == '111'
log.info mapParams['bbb']
//assert mapParams['bbb']== 'abc'
log.info mapParams['dd']
//assert mapParams['dd']=='023423'
```

Please you check this post.[*Get query params from request url soapui using groovy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39540142/7324872)

Comment: Wouldn't be duplicate question then?

Comment: I think that it is the same question but my english is very bad for confirn your question.