# groovy parameters repeated and separated with '&'

Tags: http, groovy, parameters, query-string

I received an http request with one query parameter repeated and separated with `'&'`.

For example: `/xxx/yyy?name=mark&name=luke&name=vincent`

How can I take the multiple values of parameters name?
Please don't tell me to use `"name=mark,luke,vincent"` - I can't.

Comment: Is this with grails?

Comment: soap ui, mock groovy

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41581611/how-to-parse-a-url-to-fetch-its-parameters-in-groovy) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535861/get-query-params-from-request-url-soapui-using-groovy)? Google is your friend...